# Composition factors and annihilation

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be an associative algebra over a field $k$ and let $M$ be some $A$-module. If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$ which annihilates $M$, i.e. if $\mathfrak{a}M=0$, then why must every composition factor of $M$ be a composition factor of $A/\mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: I think most of the content will be contained in the fact that every $A$-submodule of $M$ is "actually" an $A/\mathfrak{a}$-submodule.

Comment: ANSWER: Let $E$ be a composition factor of $M$. Then $E$ is an irreducible $A$-submodule of $M$, and since $\mathfrak{a}M=0$ we can consider $E$ as an irreducible $A/\mathfrak{a}$-module. Since every irreducible $A/\mathfrak{a}$-module must occur as a composition factor in its regular representation, we are done.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let E be a composition factor of M. Then E is an irreducible A-submodule of M, and since aM=0 we can consider E as an irreducible A/a-module. Since every irreducible A/a-module must occur as a composition factor in its regular representation, we are done.